# JavaFX pagination factory not working

Tags: javafx

I am trying to create a basic pagination control in a controller and it looks like is not being called the cratePage method :
This is the initialize method:

```
      public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    //bla
    pagination = new Pagination(githubRepo.getTotalCount()/rowsPerPage+1,0);
    //pagination.setPageFactory(this::createPage);
    //pagination.setPageFactory((Integer pageIndex) -> createPage(pageIndex));
    pagination.setPageFactory(new Callback<Integer, Node>() {

        @Override
        public Node call(Integer pageIndex) {

            return createPage(pageIndex);
        }
    });



}
```

and this is the createPage method:

```
private ListView createPage(int pageIndex) {
    //etc
    listView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(repoArray));

    return listView;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When using fxml+controller you shouldn't do assignments to fields that correspond to parts of the fxml since you just replace the value injected. In your case you replace the existing `Pagination` that was inserted to the scene by `FXMLLoader` with a new one you create yourself but never insert to a scene. It's this new `Pagination` that you adjust leaving the one displayed in the scene unmodified.

You need to get rid of the constructor invocation:

```
@FXML
private Pagination pagination;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    //bla
    pagination.setPageCount(githubRepo.getTotalCount()/rowsPerPage+1);
    pagination.setCurrentPageIndex(0);
    pagination.setPageFactory(new Callback<Integer, Node>() {

        @Override
        public Node call(Integer pageIndex) {
            return createPage(pageIndex);
        }
    });

}
```

This of course only works if the `Pagination` is part of the fxml:

```xml
...
<Pagination fx:id="pagination" ...>
...
```